# task synchronization

Tags: c#, synchronization, task, task-parallel-library

I have an algorithm which is executted in task from tpl.

From each iteration I want to execute an event handler which update the progress bar in winforms client (throught mvp preseter)

```
public delegate void NotifyAboutIterationEnd(int iteration);

public event NotifyAboutIterationEnd Notify;

 var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
   {
       foreach (..
       {
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(p =>
                                             {
                                                 Notify(++index);
                                             },CancellationToken.None,TaskCreationOptions.None,Scheduler);
           foreach (..
```

The problem is that, in debug mode I see first is executing the code from the main task. When this code is over, then debugger goes to the inner task. How can I synchronize it? I want to update the progress bar in each iteration. Now the effect is that, I have algorithm result in datagridview already and then I see working (updateing) progress bar :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're `Scheduler` variable is the `TaskScheduler` instance for the UI synchronization context and so you're just trying to be consistent by using the Task API isntead of just using `Control/Window::Invoke` directly?

The only way to synchronize would be to call `t.Wait()`. This will obviously block your parallel work from continuing until the call to `Notify` completes, but if you really need the UI to be synchronized with the progress then this is the only way.